# RecyclerView Can't Scroll While Refreshing From API (OkHttp), Crashes With IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView crashes with an IndexOutOfBoundsException while scrolling after attempting to refresh the data.

**Desired functionality:** After API request has successfully populated RecyclerView once, I'd like to refresh the RecyclerView and be able to scroll up and down while it refreshes.

**Current functionality:** If I don't scroll while refreshing the data, the app doesn't crash. If I scroll after making a refresh request, it crashes with an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I've spent several weeks trying to troubleshoot this problem without posting a question, and I believe I've tried enough potential solutions to justify asking Stack Overflow for guidance. There are countless questions on here with the same subject, but unfortunately none of them have solved my problem. Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Here are some solutions other people have suggested:

1. To use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but I understand this to
   be considered a 'last resort' in the Android documentation
2. To call list.clear before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
3. To get the position of all current items in the data set to an Integer called 'position' with adapter.getItemCount(), and then pass that to adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position)
4. To set adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
5. To call mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear() and mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
6. Apparently if the RecyclerView is inside a LinearLayout, 'notify' methods don't work (this might pertain to an old bug in Android which may be fixed now, but I'm not sure.)

All of these suggestions result in a 'Fatal Exception'.

My app uses five files:

- JobsAdapter (Adapter)
- JobsListItem (Getters and Setters)
- JobsOut (Fragment)
- jobs_recyclerview
- jobs_listitem

I've only included code for the Adapter and Fragment, because I'm confident that the layout files and Getters and Setters are well formed.

**Fragment:**

```
public class JobsOut extends Fragment {

String jobId;
String jobTitle;
String jobNumber;
String jobStartTime;
String dispatchType;

@BindView(R.id.jobsOutRecyclerView) RecyclerView jobsOutRecyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.fab) FloatingActionButton refreshFab;

private List<JobsListItem> dispatch;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mJobsOutAdapter;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager dispatchLayoutManager;

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Handler handler = new Handler();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_test, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    dispatch = new ArrayList<>();
    jobsOutRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    dispatchLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    jobsOutRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(dispatchLayoutManager);

    downloadDispatch();

    refreshFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            downloadDispatch();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dispatch.clear();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this);
}

private void downloadDispatch() {
    final okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url("url")
            .header("X_SUBDOMAIN", "SUBDOMAIN")
            .header("X-AUTH-TOKEN", "API_KEY")
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();

                JSONObject getRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONObject metaObject = getRootObject.getJSONObject("meta");
                final String row_count = metaObject.getString("total_row_count");
                {

                    if (row_count.equals("0")) {
                        // do something for no jobs
                    } else {
                        JSONObject getArray = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray opportunitiesArray = getArray.getJSONArray("opportunities");

                        for (int i = 0; i < opportunitiesArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject opportunity = opportunitiesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            jobId = opportunity.getString("id");
                            jobTitle = opportunity.getString("subject");
                            jobNumber = opportunity.getString("number");
                            jobStartTime = opportunity.getString("starts_at");
                            dispatchType = opportunity.getString("customer_collecting");

                            // Take Strings from response and send them to JobsListItem
                            final JobsListItem item = new JobsListItem(jobId, jobTitle, jobNumber, jobStartTime, dispatchType);

                            // If the adapter hasn't been created, do this
                            if (mJobsOutAdapter == null) {
                                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mJobsOutAdapter = new JobsAdapter(dispatch, getContext());
                                        jobsOutRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJobsOutAdapter);
                                        dispatch.add(item);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            // If the adapter has been created, just do this
                            else if (mJobsOutAdapter != null) {
                                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        dispatch.add(item);
                                        mJobsOutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "IO exception caught: ", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "TAG exception caught: ", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class JobsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<JobsListItem> mJobsListItem;
private Context context;

public JobsAdapter(List<JobsListItem> mJobsListItem, Context context) {
    this.mJobsListItem = mJobsListItem;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.jobs_listitem, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final JobsListItem mJobsListItemViewHolder = this.mJobsListItem.get(position);

    // holders go here and do things with text and what-not
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mJobsListItem.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // BindView's with ButterKnife go here and all that jazz

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

**Logcat from crash:**

```
26404-26404 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                          Process: uk.co.plasmacat.techmate, PID: 26404
                          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 4(offset:4).state:16
                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1325)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1061)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1695)
                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2883)
                              at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10063)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2630)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2307)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3127)
                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
                              at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10283)
                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4522)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4353)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3946)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3920)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3946)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3920)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6341)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6315)
                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6265)
                              at 

android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6444)
                                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
                                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6415)
                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6467)
                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:615)
                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

If you have the time, I would thoroughly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Hi @g-singh, I should have said, I've also tried that. Same error.

Comment: if you willing to put on github(unless privacy issue). I would love to take look at it.Log cat Doesn't provide enough info.

Comment: You make too many calls to `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Actually once per one JSON entry. That's ineffective and maybe it's related to the crash. I suggest to add all your data items to the "dispatch" `List` and then after the for-cycle you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` only once.

Comment: have you tried this steps together  : 1- call `dispatch.clear();` inside your `onResponse`    2- call `mJobsOutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` just after your `for loop` ( of `onResponse`)

Comment: Good idea, guys, it never occurred to me that notifyDataSetChanged was being called on a loop. I've made your suggested changes, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re trying to do is fairly common, your index out of bounds happens when the recycler view needs to ask its adapter for data (because it has scrolled) and the position it needs doesn’t exist in the Adatper. E.g.: the adapter tries to grab item number “N” and the data contains N-1 (or less).

This is most of the times due to a number of factors:

1. Threading. This should all be handled (for the most part) on the UI Thread (notifications and what not). The network request is obviously happening in a background thread, I think that eventually `onResponse` is now back on the main thread (otherwise you’d get other exceptions). Double check it my testing `Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()` (or similar).
2. You’re doing a lot of (unneeded) work on the Main Thread. You receive the response from the network, and you parse JSON and create objects in the Main Thread… why not offload all the work and *once you have a list of items*, pass it onto the adapter.
3. You’re inefficiently calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time (this is bad). Why not use the (included in Android) `DiffUtil` class to only notify of the changed range? Allow me to point you to a good sample of how it works: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#diffing-larger-changes

It should take you about 30 minutes to implement these changes and it will make your code way more robust.

Bonus points if you use RXJava to make it a stream :-)

*note:* You should create the adapter once, and then simply call `setItems(your_list_of_items)` every time you have new data. The DiffUtil and adapter should know how to deal with this. You have a lot of “business logic” there in your activity/fragment/networking code that doesn’t belong there. All your “onResponse” method should do is prepare the data and pass it to the class responsible for managing the data (the adapter). When I see this `// If the adapter hasn't been created, do this`, I frown. Why is this code creating the adapter here? Who’s gonna test this? What if you change OKHttp with something else? (why not use retrofit and make it even easier?).

I mean, there are multiple things you can do to make your life as a programmer easier, you’re not making use of the solutions available to you.

Comment: Hi Martin, this is a fantastic answer, thanks for taking the time to write it. I haven't tested your suggestions, but I will give it a good go and loop back with the results. Defending my inefficient code; I have only been doing this for a month, so my understanding is still layman, but I enjoy using libraries to make my life easier, and every day I'm learning more to do the same. This answer will no doubt be a great help. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome. Apologies if it sounds mean, it’s not the intention. I was trying to quickly put you back on track. My suggestion is to peek at Retrofit + GSON (or any other JSON parser). Will make your life *a lot simpler* unless you have “legal” objections to include open source code (tho if you use OkHttp, you’re already using Square’s libraries). Especially if you’re new, using Retrofit (which uses OKHTTP internally) will abstract the problems until you have more knowledge to deal with them yourself. Then you get lazy and use Retrofit anyway. :-)

Comment: No problem my friend, it's well received. When I was first learning how to work with API calls and JSON, I found OkHttp a little more human-readable and easier to learn basic implementation, but as time has gone on, it has occurred to me occasionally that I should be using Retrofit and a parser. This implementation is a case of old dog being too lazy to learn new tricks.

Comment: I totally hear you, but it will take you 1 hour to get this converted to retrofit/GSON (or any other parser, GSON works fine, and it’s simple/well integrated). And your code will be reduced to the “important parts”. AKA: I got this list of <SomeObject> and now I will pass it to my adapter in the UI Thread. Most of this is “for free” in terms of code you have to write.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Fantastic suggestion, Martin. Thanks for your help. I implemented a test using the DiffUtil example you linked, and it worked as intended. I'll get working on learning Retrofit and GSON now, ha!

Comment: Good to hear, Sam. Make small incremental changes :-) (You can try other GSON parsers if you want, I’ve just used GSON forever and I don’t mind too faster parsers for most of the time the parsing I have to do is very small/fast). Good luck with your learnings. o/

Answer (score -1):

While there are many good suggestions here.  One idea is to just stop the recycler from scrolling when the user interacts with a button that calls additional loading.

```
recylcerview.stopScroll();
```

Comment: This is not a reasonable or scalable solution.

Comment: If you say so, but it's still a good idea to add this code to keep it from crashing on edge cases.